# What would happen if two public keys had the same Base58 hash?

Tags: public-key, hash, base58check

If two different public keys had the same Base 58 hash, what would happen?

Could one key spend money in the other account?

What would happen to the monies received by the shared base58 hash?

Comment: But, it will likely never happen, at least not randomly, in our lifetimes: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/3205/153

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Then both of the people could spend the same coins if they were sent to their Address, rather than public key. If they instead received the money to the public keys, they couldn't spend eachother's coins.

All in all, the most important thing that would happen is that they would show RIPEMD-160 collision, which would most likely be the first one ever. A pretty improbable sight.

Comment: In the following question, I'm trying to understand the probability in relation to horsepower.  I'd like to account for, and track, the risk of this happening http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/5740/1878

Comment: Risk?  Essentially zero. http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/3205/153

Answer (score -1):

what about base58decode check of these 2 public key:

1KomSnwag47Eo6WKudN8YUbXyzPL1k5pzV
mzKijr2ZV5YVaCywdCLWNPorqyz2uZquRr

which is:

ce4a7fb892a72619d0f86fa33bff65f1057edef5

Comment: This is not an answer to the question or even related to it. As explained when you enter the site, stackexchange is not a chat room and is designed to have questions that are questions and answers on a question that are answers to that question. Your two addresses are the mainnet address and the testnet address of a key (or keys?) with the given pubkey hash. See https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes .